# HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: joomla, seo

http://www.songdew.com/artist.html .This is the link of my web site .Its working fine .but when i check this with seobook.com it is showing 500 internal error bellow is the link for it[http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.songdew.com%2Fartist.html&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?page=single&url=http://www.songdew.com/artist.html&useragent=1&typeProtocol=11) how to resolve it.main page is working fine .i checked ht-access and js files also.but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be java scripts not closed correctly...check the working url in ie lower versions once .you might find errors in js